# How to implicitly import a module

Tags: haskell

Module A import Data.Char

Module B imports Module A

So Module B automatically imports Data.Char ?

If not do I need to explicitly import Data.Char in Module A?

In my program, the Module B can not access the types from Data.Char

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can export `Data.Char` from module `A`.

```
module A (
    -- ... other functions
    module Data.Char
    -- ... other functions
) where

import Data.Char
```

Now when you `import A`, `Data.Char` will be available.

Comment: If we do like what you said, can we still use qualified import ? For example can we use DC (as Data.Char) in module B ?

Comment: I believe this puts everything in Data.Char into the same namespace as A, so however you import A is how these functions will be available. If you want the module qualified in B but not in C, your best bet is to not export Data.Char and to explicitly import it instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access functions and types from `Data.Char` in your module B, you need to import `Data.Char` in it, unless the module A you already imported re-exported those functions and/or types that you need in module B.

The import of `Data.Char` in module A is just for that module itself.